# $2^{2^n} - 1$ is divisible by at least $n$ distinct primes in predicate form?

Tags: prime-numbers, divisibility, predicate-logic

I have a problem that I know how to solve logically, but I can not seem to be able to write the statement of the theorem in predicate form. The exact statement is as follows.

$$\text{For every } n \in \mathbb{N}, \text{ if } n \ge 1 \text{ then }
2^{2^n} - 1 \text{ is divisible by at least } n \text{ distinct primes.}$$

I began trying to write the statement in predicate form as follows.

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N},\ n \ge 1 \implies \textit{<something here referencing each distinct prime } p_i \text{>},\ p_i\ |\ 2^{2^n} - 1$$

I do not, however, know what to put in the angled brackets. I think it might use something along the lines of $\operatorname{gcd}$ to make sure each prime is distinct, but I do not know how to check that the prime is distinct and iterate over each prime in the predicate.

Comment: You could use something like 
$\forall n \in \mathbb{N},\ n \ge 1 \implies \text{dim}(\{p_i : p_i\ |\ 2^{2^n} - 1\})<n$

Comment: Seems viable, but would that not allow duplicates? Like taking the prime $2$, $n$ times and calling it a day? Also, I am assuming you meant $\ge$ rather than $<$.

Comment: Usually a set does not allow duplicates. It is the base for many theorems, for example all those based on induction.

Comment: To express this in first-order arithmetic you need https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/G%C3%B6del%27s_%CE%B2_function.  Actually you needed that to define $2^n$ already so it's not clear what we're supposed to assume.

Comment: Ah, so it seems like using what @N74 said would be the best way to go through things?

Comment: I think: exists i grater then n such that p_1,p_2,...p_i divides.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The simplest is probably

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N},\ n \ge 1 \implies \mathrm{card} \;\{p \;|\; p \textrm{ is prime} \wedge p\,|\, 2^{2^n} - 1 \} \ge n$$

But to write "$p \textrm{ is prime}$" more formally, you would need something like:

$$p\in \Bbb N \wedge p\gt1 \wedge \left[\forall k, (k\in\Bbb N \wedge k\ge 1 \wedge k\,|\,p)\implies (k=1\vee k=p)\right]$$

You could also write for the whole sentence:

$$\forall n \in \mathbb{N},\ n \ge 1 \implies \exists\, p\in\Bbb N^n, (\forall i \in\Bbb N, 1\le i\le n \implies p_i>1 \wedge p_i\,|\,2^{2^n}-1) \wedge (\forall i,j \in \Bbb N, 1\le i<j\le n\implies p_i\wedge p_j=1)$$

*(here I use the same $\wedge$ for "logical and" and GCD, so it may look awkward)*

However, the latter does not state that the $p_i$ are primes. But it's not really a problem if you consider they are pairwise coprime, hence their prime factors are distinct.

Comment: Interesting! Thank you for the response.